# Online architecture guide

Tags: architecture, java, tools, server, online

I am a newbie in gamedev, and I don't know about programmer's problems that can appear during development.

So can you advice me some best practice for starting build new online multi-player game backend?

I just saw reddraft server, and I think Spring library can also do some of its features. What is big difference? Do I need learn more spring or I have to use servers like reddraft or write these tools myself?

I know that I need to learn hard and many - and the question is - what I should to learn now at the beginning?

Thanks.

Comment: Learn 2D gamedev first, like Pong. Then Tetris or something. Then maybe a Mario clone. **Then** try coding a game server. If you're planning on doing this in 3D, add a number of 3D games to the above. I would give it at least a year, if not a couple before you're far enough for this (assuming you're a proficient programmer to start).

Comment: Best advice I can give you is to make something small first, as mentioned like pong or tetris. Any type of card game (developing a card interface then trying to support more and more card game types actually helps in learning how to architect some of things and the like).

Answer (score 6):

I know this is disheartening, but I'd recommend getting a bit of single-player development experience before coding a multiplayer game.  Multiplayer development has all of the issues of single-player, plus a hundred more.  Doing a single-player game will let you learn some of the programming problems that can appear.  When you no longer consider yourself a gamedev newbie, go for multiplayer.

Comment: a little chime in here.. There is complication to networking, but if you can develop a generic enough input interface, then it should not matter where the 'commands' come from.. Keyboard, Mouse.. network packet.. Just a little thought to keep in mind, but yeah, get a single player version working first so you are only debugging one aspect of a program at a time.